# Launch external activity errors on Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, mono

I was having a lot of issues today trying to add an intent to call a separate app I had written that I wanted to be available from another application. There was a lot of information on the topic but nothing seemed to work and I found out the issue and wanted to share my experience in case someone else had the same problem.

My manifest included the item

```
<activity android:name="CraftTabs">
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and I was trying to launch it with the code

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
intent.SetClassName("com.mycompany.calculator", "com.mycompany.calculator.CraftTabs");
StartActivity(intent);
```

which resulted in an activity not found exception.

Answer (score 1):

**Give fully qualified name in manifest file.**

```
<activity android:name="com.mycompany.calculator.CraftTabs">
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: In my case this did not work because the namespace was not listed
'namespace com.mycompany.calculator.CraftTabs{}'
but as 
'namespace mycompany.calculator.CraftTabs{}'
thus in code I had to write it as listed below,
'intent.SetClassName("com.mycompany.calculator", "mycompany.CraftTabs");'

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem ended up being my namespace for the "CraftTabs" activity. It was listed in mycompany and thus the manifest generated

so the solution was to just remove the com. from the SetClassName method, ie.

```
 intent.SetClassName("com.mycompany.calculator", "mycompany.CraftTabs");
```

So hopefully this helps any of you Mono coders out there save some strands of hair...

If all else fails just look up the manifest generated by Mono under
obj/debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml